# "js_be", and "js_le" in msfvenom format types

Tags: metasploit

I have a question about Msfvenom format types.

```
msfvenom --help-formats

Executable formats
asp, aspx, aspx-exe, axis2, dll, elf, elf-so, exe, exe-only, exe-service, exe-small, hta-psh, jar, jsp, loop-vbs, macho, msi, msi-nouac, osx-app, psh, psh-cmd, psh-net, psh-reflection, vba, vba-exe, vba-psh, vbs, war

Transform formats
bash, c, csharp, dw, dword, hex, java, js_be, js_le, num, perl, pl, powershell, ps1, py, python, raw, rb, ruby, sh, vbapplication, vbscript
```

what are js_be, and js_le formats?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

js_le and js_be stands for little-endian (x86) or big-endian modes respectively.
https://dev.metasploit.com/pipermail/framework/2010-March/005895.html